# IIS URL rewrite rule redirect with mask?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have a URL like this:

http://www.example.com/erf4d

(where erf4d can be any 5 character string)

I want to redirect the user to:

http://www.example.com/viewentry.aspx?ID=erf4d

I have accomplished this using rewrite rules in web.config however I would like it so that
http://www.example.com/erf4d stays in the URL bar such that the user dosen't see the "ugly" viewentry.aspx?ID=erf4d a sort of redirect mask if you will. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience URL rewrite is used the other way around. So the page is actually viewentry.aspx?ID=123 and the redirect will redirect it to /123.

I think you may be doing it the wrong way around? If you setup a URL Rewrite using the Wizard in IIS 7 for the SEO friendly URLs and use viewentry.aspx?ID=erf4d as a base, it should help get you where you need.

The redirect / rewrites work, so that if you goto test.com/123 it will work, but if you goto test.com/view.aspx?ID=123, it'll send you to test.com/123. Which is what I think you're after?

Cheers

Edit: Here's an example of something I use. It will read news.aspx?page=1 and rewrite to news/1/. But due to the rules, news/1/ actually works as well, so can be refered that way in anchors if need be.

```
            <rule name="Redirect - /news.aspx?page=a to /news/a/" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^news\.aspx$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^page=([0-9]{1,3})$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="news/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rewrite - /news/a/ to page=a" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^news/([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="news.aspx?page={R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: Thanks I played around with your example but couldn't get it to do anything :( I am not sure why I can't wrap my head around this. It is my first attempt at URL rewrite. What I am trying to accomplish is something like instagram where the user has a URL like test.com/abc123 and they see the content. In my case abc123 is the id of the content so viewContent.aspx?ID=abc123 is what should actually be shown for test.com/abc123 being entered in the URL. Is there a better way to do this than URL rewrite redirects?

Comment: here is my current rule: `<rule name="short plan" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(?!.*test.com/.*)[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}(?!.*.aspx.*)(?!.*.png.*)(?!.*.jpg.*)(?!.*.gif.*)" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.test.com/viewPlan.aspx?ID={R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>`  which takes me from test.com/abc123 and redirect to the actual page but shows the URL

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs on IIS.NET ? (http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/). The examples there pretty much match what you're attempting to achieve. You need the REDIRECT RULE and the REWRITE RULE. They work hand in hand. Not sure it can all be achieved in one rule ! Any other questions let me know.

Comment: You've been a great help, after some more trial and error I got your example to work. I do need to study this a bit more to really grasp it but your above solution has been accepted! Thank you again